# Magento 2 product visible on backend only

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, backend, visibility

I have a few products that are mainly used for partner orders and should not be on visible on frontend. But visible on backend order creations!

In other words an internal product.

I'm only looking for directions here. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can try with product visibility option to 'Not visible individualy' option.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the visibility of the product to **Not visible individualy** and it will not display at all in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display product on frontend. You need to change the product `Visibility` to `Not visible individualy` using below admin product path.

> Admin Path: Admin >> Catalog >> Products >> Edit Product >> 
>   Visibility: Not Visible Individually

Hope it help!